# Showing related posts (custom post type) outside of the loop

Tags: loop, widgets

I'm trying the following (it's a sidebar widget in the Single New template):

```
  <ul class="featured-jobs">
  <?php
    $postid = $post->ID;
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
  ?>
  <h2><?php echo $postid; ?></h2>
  <h2><?php echo $categories; ?></h2>
  <?php // Create and run custom loop
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'news',
      'category__in' => $categories,
      'post__not_in' => $postid,
      'posts_per_page'=> 3 // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    );
    $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
    $custom_posts->query( $args );
    while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
  ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  <li class="see-all-positions"><a href="http://www.pixelmatic.com/open-jobs/">See All Positions >></a></li>
  </ul>
```

But as it turns out, `$postid` comes up blank and `$categories` outputs as `Array`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using $wp_query global variable:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_post = get_queried_object();
$post_id = $_post->ID;
```

It's [somehow like that](http://wpseek.com/single_post_title/) how [`single_post_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/single_post_title) gets the title.